# Symfony - Google bot Request without session

Tags: php, symfony, session, bots

We are getting this error on our Symfony app:

```
[Thu Aug 03 08:51:32.736638 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22386] [client 66.249.93.215:58094] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function get() on null in /path/to/my/service.php:22
```

The code line where it occurs is an `onKernelRequest` listener:

```
 if (!empty($request->getSession()->get('_locale')))
```

I suppose that means that `$request` has a null `Session`, but cannot find why.

What we are sure is that this error is thrown only on google crawlers visits but we cannot figure out how to stop this error.

The only solution I've found is to create a new `Session` and assign it to `Request` if it is null, but it doesn't seem so clean nor secure.

```
if(null === $request->getSession()) {
        $session = new Session();
        $request->setSession($session);
}
```

Any idea on how to stop that errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($request->getSession() !== null && !empty($request->getSession()->get('_locale')))
```

Comment: It's a close one, but some lines after that conditional we are using `$request->getSession->set` in case that `_locale` value is empty or null, so I would need to create a new `Session()` anyway

Comment: Why don't you use the locale value of the Request object directly?

Comment: ok, after trying with your answer (it worked fine), I've taken a look at the project and found that `$session->get('_locale')` was only used in on place, so I've changed to `$request->attributes->get('_locale')` as we are using i18n for multi language routing and it worked fine and I allowed to remove some lines of code. Anyway, your answer was valid if had no chance for changes.

Comment: You might wanna change this to `$request->getLocale()` for readability reasons and not being dependent on `_locale` if the symfony team might decide to change it.

Comment: But as we are not using Symfony's default translation component, the `$request->getLocale()` return null. It is because BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle we get `_locale` value in `$request->attributes`. But after all I could use `onKernelRequest` listener `$request->setLocale()`.

Comment: I don't know the bundle but i guess they might completely overwrite the default `LocaleListener` which does exactly what you describe and sets the `$locale` in `Request` with a `onKernelRequest` listener. But i'm wondering why they would do that since the default listener also takes the value from `$request->attributes->get('_locale')` to be used in the `Request`

Comment: Found that, my fault. We were overwriting default LocaleListener and setting that to `$request->attributes`. Removed that custom LocaleListener  and obviously, we got `$request->getLocale()`. Everything solved!